# How to disable automatic capitalization while typing in Outlook 2011 on Mac?

Tags: macos, outlook, case, capitalization

When I type the word "IDs" (no quotes) in an email it changes to "Ids" automatically.

How do I disable the automatic capitalization?

Comment: This question belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the AutoCorrect Preferences, try:

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  It was the "Correct TWo INitial CApitals" setting.